# Obtaining the object the java.lang.Class<T> object for a parameterized type without constructing the class in q_uestion?

Tags: java, class

I would like to do something like:

```
Class<List<String>> targetClass = List<String>.class;
```

but that construct does not compile.

The compiler is ok with the

```
Class<List<String>> targetClass;
```

declaration, but the compiler does not like

```
List<String>.class
```

Interestingly, the compiler (1.7) allows this:

```
Class<List<String>> targetClass = (Class<List<String>>) List.class;
```

but then of course complains about an unsafe cast.

Comment: Everything becomes `List.class` after compiling, doesn't it?

Comment: @biziclop:  True, but why allow Class<List<String>>, then?

Comment: @marathon: Because the compiler pass that thinks about generics thinks that `List<String>` is a perfectly reasonable subtype, but doesn't want to deceive you into thinking that you're actually getting a `Class` object that is anything other than `List.class` when you ask for a more specific one (which doesn't exist). All generic objects of the same parent type share the same code, including static fields- like the implicit read-only `class` field.

Comment: @marathon Because that's the type of a variable and not a class literal. Of course it could be forbidden with a special rule but why would it? After all, you can obtain a `Class` instance in many other ways too, not just from a class literal.

Comment: It's a "fake" `Class<List<String>>`.  It behaves exactly as `List.class` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it seems like it should be, `List<String>` is not a class, so you cannot get the class object for that. Generics are only used to check at compile time. They are erased from the compiled bytecode.

So, the best you can do is just,

```
Class<List> clz = List.class;
```

From Effective Java, 2nd ed.,

> There are two minor exceptions to the rule that you should not use raw
> types in new code, both of which stem from the fact that generic type
> information is erased at runtime (Item 25). You must use raw types in
> class literals. The specification does not permit the use of
> parameterized types (though it does permit array types and primitive
> types) [JLS, 15.8.2]. In other words,  `List.class`, `String[].class`, and
> `int.class` are all legal, but  `List<String>.class` and `List<?>.class` are
> not

Answer (score 2):

Parameterized types aren't real types, because Java has an incomplete implementation of generics. This is why you can't actually refer to the parametric type directly in an object if you don't already know what it is- Java doesn't know either, because that information exists only at compile time.

`List<T>.class` doesn't exist because `List<T>` is, unfortunately, not actually a "real" type. `List` is, and `List.class` is the same class reference you get out of `new List<T>().class`, for any type `T`, unfortunately.

All generic objects of the same type share the same code (this is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), including static members- such as the magic language-sacred read-only field known as `.class`. The language doesn't have a mechanism to create a different `.class` for each subtype.